# How to use configuration from spring-security.xml in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to use my existing spring security xml file in spring boot. I added 
@ImportResource to load my existing xml configuration. on console its showing loading spring-security.xml.

I am getting below error:

```
 "Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.SpringBootWebSecurityConfiguration$DefaultConfigurerAdapter': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.ObjectPostProcessor<?>' available"

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

A component required a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.ObjectPostProcessor' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.ObjectPostProcessor' in your
```

**OnlineshoppingApplication.java**

```
package net.kzn.onlineshopping;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ImportResource;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"net.kzn.onlineshopping","net.kzn.shoppingbackend"})
@ImportResource({"classpath:spring-security.xml","classpath:dispatcher-servlet.xml"})
public class OnlineshoppingApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(OnlineshoppingApplication.class, args);
    }


}
```

**spring-security.xml**

```
<beans:beans
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

    <context:component-scan
        base-package="net.kzn.shoppingbackend" />
    <beans:bean id="passwordEncoder" 
            class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder"/>      
    <http pattern="/resources/**" security="none"/>

    <http>
        <!-- only admin access -->
        <intercept-url pattern="/manage/**" access="hasAuthority('ADMIN')" />
        <!-- only user access (who is registered) -->
        <intercept-url pattern="/cart/**" access="hasAuthority('USER')" />
        <!-- rest of the world -->  
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="permitAll" />
        <form-login login-page="/login"/>
        <access-denied-handler error-page="/access-denied"/>
    </http>

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
        <password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder"/>
            <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
                users-by-username-query="select email, password, enabled from user_detail where email = ?"
                authorities-by-username-query="select email, role from user_detail where email = ?" />
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

my pom.xml file

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>net.kzn</groupId>
    <artifactId>shoppingbackend</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>shoppingbackend</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-rest-hal-browser</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.webflow/spring-webflow -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webflow</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: can you please share your pom.xml file?

Comment: I added pom.xml file.

Comment: i have added an answer please implement and check.First use enablewebsecurity annotation and execute your application if still your issue didn't resolved try to add EnableAutoConfiguration and exclude few class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest your to please share pom.xml file and also try to use below annotation with springboot application as few things are missing.

depending on your setup, if you get any startup error related to boot autoconfiguration, you might have to exclude some auto-configuration classes, e.g. by putting this onto your Application class:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = [SecurityFilterAutoConfiguration, SpringBootWebSecurityConfiguration])
```

also add `@EnableWebSecurity` annnotation with spring-boot.

Comment: i added @EnableWebSecurity and @EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {SecurityFilterAutoConfiguration.class}) and it works for me

Comment: but still my webapp is not loading

Comment: now which errors you are facing after doing above code? and if my post helps you to fix your current issue so please up vote?

Comment: There are no error on console now but my website is not loading in browser.

Comment: is this right way to load dispatcher servlet? @ImportResource({"classpath:spring-security.xml","classpath:dispatcher-servlet.xml"})

Comment: Yes, we can load it.

Comment: in your rest controller class implement ErrorController @Override
    public String getErrorPath() {
        return "/error";
    }